# Texmaker in Ubuntu 18.04 outputs same tex file with fonts having less feathering, slightly thicker letters

Tags: fonts, texmaker, ubuntu

This is an odd problem, but texmaker seems to render a PDF from a tex file different than it did in Ubuntu 16.04.

The difference is apparent if you switch tabs between these two fonts rendered from the same tex document:

16.04 - [image: https://i.imgur.com/6bFn39T.png]

18.04 - [image: https://i.imgur.com/xNpLJc2.png]

The font used is `ebgaramond`.

It's a minor difference, but the 18.04 output looks thicker, and the letters are closer together.

Any idea what has caused this change in feathering and if there is a solution to this issue?

Comment: Ubuntu updated its ebgaramond package to a new version, so that might be it? I believe CTAN also upgraded `ebgaramond.sty`. The changelog says there was “lots of kerning and spacing” changes in the latest version.

Comment: @Davislor do you know if there's a way to downgrade?

Comment: You probably don’t want to install an obsolete package on your system, but you could download an older version of the font [from the repo](https://github.com/georgd/EB-Garamond), save it to a subdirectory of your project folder, and select it with the `Path =` option of `fontspec`.

Comment: @Davislor Thanks that helps! Can you post this as an answer, and if possible provide the code for the `Path =`, section of `fontspec`?

Currently I just have: `\usepackage{ebgaramond}` so not sure where fontspec would go or what the syntax looks like.